# jQuery image load, append to multiple div's

Tags: javascript, jquery, preload

I am using the following code to preload an image:

```
$('<img src="'+ Image +'">').load(function() {
  $(this).appendTo('#background');
  $('#background').show();
});
```

This is working like it should. But, when I try to append the image to multiple div's, it only appends the image to the last div.

Any ideas?

I have tried this, but without result:

```
$(this).appendTo('#background, #second-div');
```

Comment: Can you place an item at multiple place?

Comment: How can you append one element in 2 places if you don't make a copy of it? Append process will not make a copy

Comment: make it `$(this).clone().appendTo('#background');`

Comment: @gurvinder372 this loads the image again..

Comment: @Jvd obviously as the source of both (original and cloned) image is same.

Comment: @gurvinder372 I understand, but I mean; a new HTTP request is made. So the image URL will be called twice.

Comment: new HTTP request is made but since the URL is same it will be retrieved from the browser's cache itself.

Comment: @gurvinder372 I think my browser is not caching the image correctly, then. Because I get 2 HTTP 200 requests. Also, I can see my bandwidth go up, twice the image size. Any ideas?

Comment: The 200 status was due to a PHP image which was not caching properly.. Now fixed!

Answer (score 0):

As referencing to your provided JS code. Assuming that you might have declared **background** as **id**. Try to declare it as a **class** and replace the below snippet. Hopefully, I guess it works.

```
$('<img src="'+ Image +'">').load(function() {
    $(this).appendTo('.background');
    $('.background').show();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If you pass a selector to `.appendTo` that matches more than one element, [jQuery will clone your reference element](https://j11y.io/jquery/#v=1.11.2&fn=appendTo) - *with all event listeners* - and append the cloned element.

As your reference element is an image with an onload listener, the added element will also be an image with an onload listener, and you will be creating an infinite number of images.

The reason this appears to you as "not working" and not as flooding your browser with images, is likely because you are adding them to a hidden container, and you never reach the `.show` call.

One solution would be to use jQuery's [`one`](http://api.jquery.com/one/) handler, which verifies that the `load` callback is fired exactly once:

[Fiddle with infinite images](https://jsfiddle.net/x8263bx9/)

[Fiddle with `one` image](https://jsfiddle.net/3sok5sj2/)

The solution suggested in comments, with calling `.clone()` yourself before appending the image to a new - single - target, is also working, exactly because you're calling `.clone()` and not `.clone(true)` which is what `.appendTo` does internally, and which is what's causing the `load` listener to be preserved for the cloned object as well.

[Fiddle with `clone`](https://jsfiddle.net/qs2nno3L/)

Comment: Thank you! I really appreciate the explanation.